# Laravel: update database record without having to set properties one by one

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I'm updating a db record in laravel using eloquent like this:

($request is an object with the properties I want to update)

```
$book = Book::find($request->id)
$book->title = $request->title;
$book->author = $request->author;
$book->publisher = $request->publisher;
.
.
.
$book->something = $request->something;
$book->save();
```

It works fine but I wonder if it's possible to do it whitout having to explicity name the properties one by one since the names in $request are exactly the same as those of the model, something like:

```
$book = $request;
$book->save();
```

Comment: Is `$request` a `Illuminate\Http\Request` object?

Comment: Yes, it is, with the data I send to the controller

Answer (score 0):

```
$book = Book::find($request->id);
$book->update($request->all());
```

More info here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#updates

However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a **fillable** or **guarded** attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

A mass-assignment vulnerability occurs when a user passes an unexpected HTTP parameter through a request, and that parameter changes a column in your database you did not expect. For example, a malicious user might send an is_admin parameter through an HTTP request, which is then passed into your model's create method, allowing the user to escalate themselves to an administrator.

Read more about in [documentations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment).